# GroupBy : how to handle empty groups?

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I am trying to group elements from a list of custom objects.

The object:

```
Public class MyObj
{
    public string groupName{ get; set; }
    public int year{ get; set; }

    public MyObj(string groupName)
    {
        this.GroupName = groupName;
    }    

    public MyObj(string groupName, int year)
    {
        this.GroupName = groupName;
        this.Year = year;
    }
}
```

The list :

```
List<MyObj> list = new List<MyObj>();
list.Add(new MyObj("group1", 2012));
list.Add(new MyObj("group1", 2013));
list.Add(new MyObj("group2", 2012));
list.Add(new MyObj("group2", 2013));
list.Add(new MyObj("group3"));
list.Add(new MyObj("group3"));
```

If I do something like :

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, MyObj>> listMyObj = list.GroupBy(o => o.Year);
```

"group3" will ne be included in the result list.
How can I group my MyObjs by Year and keep an empty "group3" item in the result ?

Comment: That's simply not true - and I have just checked that in LINQPad. It will be included in the grouping with a grouping key == 0 (`default(int)`). If the key was an unset reference or nullable type, then it would be grouped under key == `null`.

Comment: Have you tried running this code? If you fix various errors ("year" instead of "Year", various missing parentheses, incorrect type for listMyObj), you should find that the objects where you haven't set a year do get a group with key 0.

Comment: -1 for an incorrect assumption which could be checked easily. You should also provide compiling code if you are already showing sample data.

Comment: Just tried your code I get three groups one where year is 2013, one where year is 2012 and one where year is 0. If I change the year to be nullable then I still get three groups but the last group has year as null.

Comment: I would use a `Nullable<int>` if the year can be undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange that you want some groups accepting even empty ones, your query is wrong because the `Where` has already filtered out all the elements with `q.DateRealisation == DateTime.MinValue`, this would work for you:

```
var qualifs2 = lstQualifs.GroupBy(q => q.Contrat)
                         .Select(g=>g.Where(q => q.DateRealisation != DateTime.MinValue))
                         .SelectMany(g=>g);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get a group. The group's key will be `0`, because `default(int) == 0`.

When you don't assign a class member variable, it's set to its default value. For reference types that's `null`, for aliased integral/floating point types that's `0`, and for user defined `struct`s that's their values filled with the default.